# Xamarin Forms MultiPage<T> example

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, multipage

I am thinking to implement a custom tabbed page with some custom functionality and I thought about using [MultiPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.multipage-1?view=xamarin-forms).
I am thinking about that because it seems to be the base class of the Forms's `TabTabbedPage` and would like to actually have a page at the bottom to display the buttons and the top space to display come content pages based on the selection(of the user).

Currently I only added 2 pages on the `MultiPage` and the last page from the data set is being displayed but I can't shrink its height so that I can add another content page below to add the buttons. I tried to set the `HeightRequest` on the pages but with no effect.

Does anyone have at hand some samples involving the `MultiPage` or knows how to change the `ContentPage` width or height?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This link may be helpful to you:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MultiPage.cs

Comment: Thanks @CherryBu I already checked that but can't see something that enables me to get to the desired layout :(

Comment: Can you share your layout and some gif files about your issue here?